# Is the 仮定形 used only to make the conditional?

Tags: grammar

toru --aEiou--> tore --joshi--> toreba.

Is the ba-joshi the only suffix that can be added to the kateikei form of the verb?

Comment: No, as you seem to have [discovered for yourself](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19087/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern Japanese, 仮定形 is used almost exclusively to make a conditional.
The definition in a Japanese dictionary 大辞林 suggests that 仮定形 is alway followed by “ば”.

One apparent exception is “すれども” but this is 已然形 + “ども”.
已然形 is used in classical Japanese and means that something has been done.
已然形 is an ancestor of 仮定形 but their meaning is different.